# Get a pdf file from a website to scrape using BeautifulSoup4

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

the html source for the webpage looks like this

```
<html>
<body>
   <embed name= "random for each page" type = "application/pdf" src = "somesrc" internalid = "random">
</body>
</html>
```

I need to scrape the data from the pdf file for multiple pages with different data (they have different name and internalid). I tried to find_all embed tags but it didn't work

Comment: And what have you tried?

Comment: Also could be more specific on what data you're requiring. Sounds like you're asking for help on getting data from specific PDF files, is this correct?

Comment: @AaronS yes, I am trying to get data from the pdf files, I downloaded one manually and did it with PyPDF2 but i cant figure out how to download or read it with BeautifulSoup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To download files you can use the Requests package. BeautifulSoup is a library that is used to parse HTML, not to download files.

Now you haven't provided any information to get the URLs themselves. I would strongly urge you to post some code that you have tried to attempt to get the URLs, that way we're not just spoon feeding you answers without you understanding them.

So here's the code you could use to download them. I also assume that you've been able to get the data you want from PyPDF. The other thing you should consider is the OS module for locating the files you download before using PyPDF to extract the data. That way you're automating the process of the files being processed.

### Code Example

```
import requests
r = requests.get(url, Stream=True)
with open("filename.pdf",'wb') as pypdf:
    for chunk in r.iter_content(chunk_size=1024)
      if chunk: 
         pypdf.write(ch)
```

### Explanation

We use the get method of request on the URL for the pdf file. The `stream=True`, this defers downloading the file until we ask it to. It downloads the binary headers first though and waits for us to tell it what to do with the binary data body.

`r.iter_content` - This splits up the file into 1024 bytes chunks.

We then loop around those chunks to write the file.

Comment: the url looks something like this "https://sitename/report.aspx?cid=2037&mid=31&exid=624&rpttype=GRPQR". I get the mid as input and use 15 exid and output a result for each exid. I tried to parse the page with beautifulsoup , but I couldn't figure out how to get data from the pdf. then I realised it was an embedded pdf and thought i had to download it and use PyPDF2 to get the data.

Answer (score 0):

Try just filtering out all tags with type attribute "application/pdf" and then extracting the `src` attribute to download the pdf

like this

```py
pdfTags = soup.findAll(attrs={"type" : "application/pdf"})
for p in pdfTags:
    print(p['src'])
```